# How to add a Lottie animation in Java programatically

Tags: java, android, android-studio, lottie

I tried to add Lottie Animation to Java (Android) programmatically, but I keep failing. I will show my code below I need to change from drawable to Lottie.

This is the code for drawables:

```
if (status.equals("connect")) {

            vpnBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.but_connect_light);
            logTv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.font_color));

        } else if (status.equals("connecting")) {

            vpnBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.but_connecting_dark);
            logTv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.font_color));

        } else if (status.equals("connected")) {

            vpnBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.but_disconnect_dark);
            logTv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.purple));

        } else if (status.equals("failed")) {

            vpnBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.but_connect_dark);

        }
```

This is the xml relating above

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/vpnBtn"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:tag="1"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:background="@drawable/but_connect_light"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"/>
```

Comment: What is exactly that you have tried? AFAIK Lottie files should be included from resources (or dynamically downloaded through an HTTP request) and after that loaded into a LottieImageView or similar. [Their docs know better than I do](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android), I suggest you take a read at them.

Comment: Literally i don't know how to do, i just tried setAnimation(R.raw..json) but i know its wrong and throwing error

Comment: Please post everything you've tried and the error it is throwing so we can further assist you. I remember that when I got started with it was quite simple task to do so I am surprised you're having trouble. [Here's a step by step guide](https://airbnb.io/lottie/#/android?id=sample-app). It would be also useful to get to know which Android OS version are you trying to run things on because *maybe and only maybe* it is not compatible.

Another remarkable thing to let us know is if you're using `androidx` or the old android libraries. Thank you!

Comment: I will post here the code and errors am a beginner thats why simple task also am getting error.

Comment: No problem, but we'd need to take a look at the Stack Trace of the error

Comment: As you ask this is the error showing  Process: com.infinite.vpn, PID: 10451
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must set an images folder before loading an image. Set it with LottieComposition#setImagesFolder or LottieDrawable#setImagesFolder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I achieved this with the solution below:

```
String vpnsBtn;

if (check.equals("night")){

        switch (status) {
            case "connect":

                vpnBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                vpnsBtn = ("disconnected.json");
                logTv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.font_color));

                break;
            case "connecting":

                vpnBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                vpnsBtn = ("connectingg.json");
                logTv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.font_color));

                break;
            case "connected":

                vpnBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                vpnsBtn = ("connected.json");
                logTv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.purple));

                break;
            case "failed":

                vpnBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                vpnsBtn = ("disconnected.json");

                break;
        }

    }else {

        switch (status) {
            case "connect":

                vpnBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                vpnsBtn = ("disconnected.json");
                logTv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.font_color));

                break;
            case "connecting":

                vpnBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                vpnsBtn = ("connectingg.json");
                logTv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.font_color));

                break;
            case "connected":

                vpnBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                vpnsBtn = ("connected.json");
                logTv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.purple));

                break;
            case "failed":

                vpnBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                vpnsBtn = ("disconnected.json");

                break;
        }
    }

    LottieAnimationView animationView = findViewById(R.id.vpnBtn);
    animationView.setImageAssetsFolder("vpnconnect");
    animationView.setAnimation(vpnsBtn);
    animationView.loop(true);
    animationView.playAnimation();
```

I hope this will help others who want to use dynamic buttons with Lottie on Android.

Answer (score 6):

The above solutions didn't work for me, crashing the app.

Try using this:

`animationView.setAnimation(R.raw.your_lottie_file)`

or, adding it to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67567633) from Infinite

```
String vpnsBtn;

if (check.equals("night")){

    switch (status) {
        case "connect":

            vpnBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            vpnsBtn = R.raw.disconnected;
            logTv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.font_color));

            break;
        case "connecting":

            vpnBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            vpnsBtn = R.raw.connectingg;
            logTv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.font_color));

            break;
        case "connected":

            vpnBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            vpnsBtn = R.raw.connected
            logTv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.purple));

            break;
        case "failed":

            vpnBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            vpnsBtn = R.raw.disconnected;

            break;
    }

}else {

    switch (status) {
        case "connect":

            vpnBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            vpnsBtn = R.raw.disconnected;
            logTv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.font_color));

            break;
        case "connecting":

            vpnBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            vpnsBtn = R.raw.connectingg;;
            logTv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.font_color));

            break;
        case "connected":

            vpnBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            vpnsBtn = R.raw.connected;;
            logTv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.purple));

            break;
        case "failed":

            vpnBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            vpnsBtn = R.raw.disconnected;

            break;
    }
}

LottieAnimationView animationView = findViewById(R.id.vpnBtn);
animationView.setImageAssetsFolder("vpnconnect");
animationView.setAnimation(vpnsBtn);
animationView.loop(true);
animationView.playAnimation();
```

Answer (score 3):

First Use this **dependency**:

```
implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.6.1'
```

Add `LottieAnimationView` in xml:

```
 <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView       
        android:id="@+id/animation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
        app:lottie_fileName="loading.json"
        app:lottie_loop="true"
        app:lottie_speed="1" />
```

Change animation according to your use:

```
animation.setAnimation("loading.json");
```

**Note**: Add your lottie animation json file in asset folder.

Answer (score 1):

For using Lottie I did these:

In `build.gradle(:app)` add this and sync:

```
implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:$lottieVersion'
```

then, add `assets` file. Then, add the JSON files there. Then, go to `activity_main.xml` file, add:

```
<com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
            android:id="@+id/lav_actionBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
            app:lottie_fileName="circle-load.json" --> add your JSON file name 
            app:lottie_loop="true" />
```